# Collapsing toolbar layout with tabs, collapse toolbar only when tabs reaches toolbar in android

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Sorry if i have not formatted the question in meaning full manner,i'll explain on what my problem.

I want to implement tabs inside a collapsing toolbar layout, everything is working fine as expected but the problem is with toolbar collapsing. I want toolbar to be collapsing only when tabs reaches till toolbar (Just like google play) but with my code toolbar is collapsing immediately when user swipes up

And when i scroll down, i want the tabs and toolbar to come. This is my xml code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    tools:context=".activity.NavigationDrawerActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
        android:layout_height="256dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/winner_edge"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <AutoCompleteTextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/searchView"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:hint="Search your app"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/black"
                        android:popupBackground="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/search_view_cursor"
                        android:background="@color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/appName"
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:text="Winner Edge"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is what i'm expecting [image: Here toolbar is pushed by tabs]

This is what my code doing [image: You can see the toolbar is already collapsed]

Please help me on how to achieve this and comment if you need any further info to solve this problem

Comment: you need to put the toolbar as the direct child of appbarlayout not inside the collapsingtoolbarlayout i think

Comment: I tried with your suggestion, but in vain because scroll animations are not working with it and also toolbar went into status bar. Any ideas?

Comment: no sorry i just read the documentation your toolbar is in the right place, try removing the imageview `@+id/header` and also remove the `tablayout` from inside the `collapsingtoolbarlayout`, essentially just keep the toolbar in the collapsingtoolbarlayout

Comment: No i need image view because i'm planning to replace viewpager of images with image(just like google play). If i keep tab layout outside then we can't get the desired output as tab layout don't know where to get placed

Comment: @Bhargav got any idea?

Comment: I dont have enough experience with this you should prolly use material view pager library by florent if you want image in your collapsing toolbar layout https://github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager